# How do i fix an insertBefore() error in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-ui

```html
<body>

      <div class="container mt-4">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-car text-success"></i>
      My<span class="text-success ">Car</span>List</h1>

      <form id="car-form">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="worker">Empoloyee ID</label>
      <input type="text" id="worker" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="carVin">Car Vin</label>
      <input type="text" id="carVin" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="strTime">Start time</label>
      <input type="text" id="strTime" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="endTime">End time</label>
      <input type="text" id="endTime" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Car" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">

      </form>
    
</body>
```

```html
 <div class="container mt-4">
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
  <i class="fas fa-car text-success"></i>
  My<span class="text-success ">Car</span>List</h1>
  
  <form id="car-form">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="worker">Empoloyee ID</label>
   <input type="text" id="worker" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="carVin">Car Vin</label>
   <input type="text" id="carVin" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="strTime">Start time</label>
   <input type="text" id="strTime" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="endTime">End time</label>
   <input type="text" id="endTime" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Add Car" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
  
  </form>
  
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-dark mt-3"> 
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Employee ID</th>
     <th>Car Vin</th>
     <th>Start time</th>
     <th>End time</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="car-list"></tbody>
  </table>
  
   <!div id="my-filter" class="msg" >
   <!input type="submit" value="Filter Car" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
  
 </div>
```

I'm setting a new div used to display error messages for my program using the insertBefore() method, but it doesn't seem to be working. How  would I fix this?
What do I need to change?

```
class UI {
  static displayCars(){}

  static addCarToList(car){
    const list = document.querySelector('#car-list');
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${car.worker}</td>
    <td>${car.carVin}</td>
    <td>${car.strTime}</td>
    <td>${car.endTime}</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm 
    delete">Clear</a></td>`;
    list.appendChild(row);
  }

  static showAlert(message, className){
    const div =document.createElement('div');
    div.className = `alert alert-${className}`;
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const form = document.querySelector('#car-form');
    // before(newnode, existingnode)
    // IM HAVING THE ERROR LINE 49
    container.insertBefore(div, form);

    // Vanish in 3 secs
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.alert').remove(),3000);
  }
}
```

The program would display the car array but it would not do the alert message on line 111

```
if(worker === ''|| carVin === ''|| strTime === '' || endTime === ''){
  UI.showAlert('Please fill all fields', 'danger');  //LINE 111 
} else {

  // Instatiate car
  const car = new Car(worker, carVin, strTime, endTime);

  // Add car to list 
  // UI.addCarToList(car); ///

  // Add car to local storage
  Store.addCar(car);
  UI.displayCars(); ///

  // Show Success msg
  UI.showAlert('Car Added', 'success');

  //Clear fields
  UI.clearFields();
}
```

[![ERROR DESCRIPTION][2]][2]
app.js:56 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at Function.showAlert (file:///C:/Users/awbak/Desktop/WEBSITES/My%20Car%20List/app.js:56:13)
    at HTMLFormElement. (file:///C:/Users/awbak/Desktop/WEBSITES/My%20Car%20List/app.js:120:6)

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1yIM.png
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/koiYh.png
```

Comment: It's telling you that `#car-form` is not a child of `container` so you cannot insert `div` into `container` before `form`. Without seeing your HTML, we cannot help

Comment: I have a div with class(container) then a form with id(car-form)

Answer (score 0):

As your error states, your `form` is not inside the `container`. The `referenceNode`, so the `form`, needs to be inside of the `container`,

[insertBefore reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Comment: I have a div with class(container) then a form with id(car-form)

Comment: Is the form inside the container (because the error doesn't say it is)? Can you post a snippet of your html?